# How to write file with Chinese filename

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using ES6 with WDIO to write reports with Chinese filename.

```
        fs.writeFileSync(
            './測試.text',
            "hello".toString(),
            'utf-8');
```

The above code would generate this odd filename

```
"\345\234\260\345\215\200_\346\226\260\350\216\212\345\211\257\351\203\275\345\277\203_\345\235\252\346\225\270_0~50_\345\261\213\351\275\241_0~1_\345\271\264\344\273\275_2019~2020.txt"
```

How do I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as per [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)
`fs.writeFileSync` accepts file with the following types `<string> | <Buffer> | <URL> | <integer>` .

You can use `Buffer` like so:

```
fs.writeFileSync(Buffer('./測試.text'), "hello".toString(), 'utf-8');
```

and it should create a file with the name you need, at least it worked for me on Mac.